# Issue loading the backbone view for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, requirejs

I want to load one of my javascript automatically on the load of my html page.
The html page on load of which I want to load my js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="/static/js/LoginApp.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Backbone Tutorial Blogroll App</h1>
        <button type="button" id="newButton">Click Me!</button>
        <script src="/static/js/require.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/LoadView.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The javascript I want to load is

**LoadView.js**

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'LoadView',
        'text!NewViewCheck.html',

        ], function($, _, Backbone, LoadView, NewViewCheck) {
    var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {}
    });
    TheView = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: new Task(),
        events: {
            'click #newButton': 'initializeView',
        },
        //'template' provides access to instance data when rendering the view
        template: _.template(NewViewCheck),
        initialize: function() {
            console.log('Inside the initialize function');
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            //this.$el.html(this.template());
            console.log(labelsLocale);
            this.$el.html(this.template({}));
            $('#dialogContent').empty().append(this.$el);
            $('#addUserDefinedOption').modal('show');
        },
        initializeView: function() {
            var theView = new TheView();
            console.log('abc');
        },
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //console.log('abc');
    })
});
```

I am getting the following error
`Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module`

Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `'text!NewViewCheck.html'` template resides in the same path as defined?

Comment: Can you please tell us the physical path of your `NetViewCheck.html` in your directory?

Comment: it is present in the public folder of my spring application.

Comment: Okay.  Can you please check your `Network` tab of your Dev Tools for any 404 errors (Page not found) with your `NetViewCheck.html` ?

Comment: No there was no 404 error because there is a problem in loading the LoadView.js file.

Comment: Can you post your build profile js of (it will be `build.js` in most of the cases) where you have configured `appDir`, `baseUrl` and `modules` etc?

Comment: I have not made any such file till now.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have:

```
<script src="/static/js/LoadView.js"></script>
```

The [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch) says:

> If you manually code a script tag in HTML to load a script with an anonymous define() call, this error can occur.

And that's what you're doing.

And in solutions:

> - Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API. Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that have define() calls in them.
> - If you manually code an HTML script tag, be sure it only includes named modules, and that an anonymous module that will have the same name as one of the modules in that file is not loaded.

So simply load it using requireJS from your main file or name the module